# Я хочу добавить Media Player себе в окно диалога, как это сделать?

Tags: c++, qt, указатели, mediaplayer

Есть в примерах [Media Player](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-example.html), я хочу добавить его себе в окно диалога. Почему когда я его добавляю в окно диалога выкидывает исключение :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
...
                    QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout;
...

                    QCoreApplication::setApplicationName("Player Example");
                    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("QtProject");
                    QCoreApplication::setApplicationVersion(QT_VERSION_STR);
                    QCommandLineParser parser;
                    QCommandLineOption customAudioRoleOption("custom-audio-role",
                                                             "Set a custom audio role for the player.",
                                                             "role");
                    parser.setApplicationDescription("Qt MultiMedia Player Example");
                    parser.addHelpOption();
                    parser.addVersionOption();
                    parser.addOption(customAudioRoleOption);
                    parser.addPositionalArgument("url", "The URL(s) to open.");
                    //parser.process(this);
                    Player *player;

                    if (parser.isSet(customAudioRoleOption))
                        player->setCustomAudioRole(parser.value(customAudioRoleOption));

                    if (!parser.positionalArguments().isEmpty() && player->isPlayerAvailable()) {
                        QList<QUrl> urls;
                        for (auto &a: parser.positionalArguments())
                            urls.append(QUrl::fromUserInput(a, QDir::currentPath(), QUrl::AssumeLocalFile));
                        player->addToPlaylist(urls);
                    }
                    player->show();
                    layout->addWidget(player,2,0,1,2);
...
```

Сам [Player](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtmultimedia-multimediawidgets-player-player-h.html) наследуется от public QWidget:

```
class Player : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
}
```

Как Player можно расположить не в выпадающем окне, а встроить в диалоговое окно ? Получить что то вроде такого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `Player *player;` и тут же `if (parser.isSet(customAudioRoleOption))`, у вас пустой указатель, поэтому и упало приложение. Инициализируйте указатель, создав объект `Player`

Comment: @gil9red Можно пример пожалуйста , очень вам буду благодарен

Comment: @gil9red                   Player *player= new Player(this);
                        player->addToPlaylist(model->data(model->index(index.row(),2)).toString());
                        //player->show();
                        layout->addWidget(player,2,0,1,2);

Comment: @gil9red  всё вроде получилось

Comment: Круто ведь :) Кст, если возможно, создавайте объекты на стеке, например сохраняя их в полях класса, тогда не нужно будет следить за выделением и освобождением памяти

Comment: @gil9red  Если можно маленький пример как это реализовать?

Comment: `Player *player= new Player(this)` выполняется в каком-то вашем виджете? В заголовочном файле (`.h`) добавьте поле `Player player`. Уберите `Player *player= new Player(this); `, а вместо `player->` пишите `player.`, например `player->addToPlaylist` -> `player.addToPlaylist`. Если где-то передается указатель на `player` например `layout->addWidget(player,2,0,1,2);`, то его нужно будет так вызывать: `layout->addWidget(&player,2,0,1,2);`. Уверены что вам нужно с этим париться? :)

Comment: Вот мой пример: https://github.com/gil9red/ScreenShot/blob/master/UScreenShot.h#L46 и https://github.com/gil9red/ScreenShot/blob/master/UScreenShot.cpp#L102

Comment: @gil9red  спасибо большое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема была в не инициализированном указателе на `Player`:

```
...
Player *player;

if (parser.isSet(customAudioRoleOption))
...
```

Поэтому и упало приложение